# Why does the FINISH function run multiple times (in veins)?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I know in veins the FINISH function is done when the car comes out of the simulation.

In My simulation, the car travel time is calculated.This parameter is stored in a file when the cars exit the simulation by the FINISH function.
But when I check this file, there are several times recorded for each car. 
Whereas for each car, one travel time must be recorded in the file and the FINISH function is executed once (when cars are out of simulation).

I think the FINISH function is executed many times. Does anyone know the reason?
i am using omnetpp-5.0, sumo-0.25.0 and veins-veins-4.4. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would suggest using OMNeT++ methods for result recording instead of creating files yourself. See the OMNeT++ manual section on scalar and vector recording for details

Comment: @ChristophSommer Thank's a lot.

Comment: @ChristophSommer  Can you help me with this problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/57871757/10763040